# Why does MapReduce return undefined for a field that exists in document?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I am trying to debug a strange issue I am running into while running mapreduce on a collection:

For reference, here's a single document from the collection:

```
{
    "_id" : "ITOUXFWgvWs",
    "source" : "youtube",
    "insert_datetime" : ISODate("2017-04-06T22:27:43.598Z"),
    "processed" : false,
    "raw" : {
        "id" : "ITOUXFWgvWs",
        "etag" : "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/hiQtS6aptLlqxTpsYp1EJIRcoZo\"",
        "snippet" : {
            "publishedAt" : ISODate("2017-04-06T13:25:28Z"),
            "title" : "Alarm.com: The Only Smart Home App You Need",
            "channelId" : "UC_HZfoZUP36STk7SrtKYH4g",
            "description" : "All these new connected devices are awesome, but wouldn’t it be great if you could use one app for the entire connected home?  It can all come together with Alarm.com.",
            "categoryId" : "28",
            "channelTitle" : "Alarm.com",
            "thumbnails" : {
                "default" : {
                    "height" : 90,
                    "width" : 120,
                    "url" : "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ITOUXFWgvWs/default.jpg"
                },
                "standard" : {
                    "height" : 480,
                    "width" : 640,
                    "url" : "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ITOUXFWgvWs/sddefault.jpg"
                },
                "high" : {
                    "height" : 360,
                    "width" : 480,
                    "url" : "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ITOUXFWgvWs/hqdefault.jpg"
                },
                "medium" : {
                    "height" : 180,
                    "width" : 320,
                    "url" : "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ITOUXFWgvWs/mqdefault.jpg"
                },
                "maxres" : {
                    "height" : 720,
                    "width" : 1280,
                    "url" : "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ITOUXFWgvWs/maxresdefault.jpg"
                }
            },
            "liveBroadcastContent" : "none",
            "localized" : {
                "title" : "Alarm.com: The Only Smart Home App You Need",
                "description" : "All these new connected devices are awesome, but wouldn’t it be great if you could use one app for the entire connected home?  It can all come together with Alarm.com."
            }
        },
        "contentDetails" : {
            "duration" : "PT37S",
            "dimension" : "2d",
            "definition" : "hd",
            "licensedContent" : false,
            "projection" : "rectangular",
            "caption" : "false"
        },
        "kind" : "youtube#video",
        "statistics" : {
            "likeCount" : "0",
            "dislikeCount" : "0",
            "favoriteCount" : "0",
            "viewCount" : "32"
        },
        "uploaded" : ISODate("2017-04-06T13:25:28Z")
    },
}
```

I am literally following the mapreduce debug steps from official mongo documentation.

Here's what my mapreduce script looks like:

```
var map = function() {
    emit("1", this._id);
};

var emit = function(key, value) {
    print("emit");
    print("key: " + key + "  value: " + tojson(value));
}

var myDoc = db.getCollection("abc").find({}).limit(1);
map.apply(myDoc);
```

And it always produces the result like this:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
connecting to: test
emit
key: 1  value: undefined
```

I expect the script to emit the `_id` since it clearly exists in the document but it doesn't.

What might be possible cause of this?

Comment: Try `var myDoc = db.getCollection("abc").findOne();` as `find()` returns a cursor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find()` always returns a cursor.

Replace it with `findOne()`

```
var myDoc = db.getCollection("abc").findOne({});
```

Or store the documents in an Array using `toArray()`

```
var myDoc = db.getCollection("abc").find({}).limit(1).toArray()[0];
```

Comment: What if I want all the records at once, I mean if there are more than > 1.

Comment: `db.getCollection("abc").find({}).toArray()` and iterate thru the values in the array in the map function.

Comment: Just curious. Why do you want to get all the records ? You can use the `query` field in the map reduce to pass the criteria to limit the documents that goes into the map reduce pipeline.

Comment: Only the title says it is MapReduce. I do not see its implementation anywhere 